# How to specify the position of an Ellipse shape on a canvas in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, graphics, shapes

I am programmatically creating an Ellipse shape but I can't find any property that specifies its position. `Lines` have X1, Y1, X2, Y2, but there is no Center, Position, X, Y, etc on an Ellipse shape. How can I do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Putting shapes in arbitrary places on the screen should probably be done so in a Canvas Panel (see @phoog's response). But if you're placing this in a Grid or some other panel instead, you could always modify the Margin property to place it where you want it.

If you wanted to do so by specifying the center point instead of the top left corner of the ellipse, you could do this:

```
Ellipse CreateEllipse(double width, double height, double desiredCenterX, double desiredCenterY)
{
    Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse { Width = width, Height = height };
    double left = desiredCenterX - (width / 2);
    double top  = desiredCenterY - (height/ 2);

    ellipse.Margin = new Thickness(left, top, 0, 0);
    return ellipse;
}
```

I haven't checked that this does exactly what you want in the compiler, but hopefully you get the idea. Again, using Canvas would be the prefered method over using Margin inside of a non-Canvas panel, but the same principle of calculating left and top would still apply:

```
Canvas.SetLeft(ellipse, desiredCenterX - (width/2))
Canvas.SetTop(ellipse, desiredCenterY - (height/2))
```

Comment: @Kamil the positioning in this case is a property of the contanier, not the ellipse itself. In a canvas, you set the `Canvas.Left` property. Weird indeed...

Comment: @heltonbiker I guess there is a reason why it's designed like this, but I didn't discovered that reason yet.

Comment: @Kamil I found this, I think it sort of explains our doubts: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx#attached_properties_usage

Comment: @heltonbiker I already solved my problem with positioning shapes on parent (by setting margin properties).

Comment: pretty sure the reason is to confuse those who just finished using the Line object thinking that it would have its own properties, or if THIS is the right way, not give us wrong ways that LOOK like correct ways. Consistency seems to be a real problem in Windows programming in general.

Answer (score 15):

Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top.  It's all in the documentation on "How to Draw an Ellipse or a Circle" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751563.aspx

In C# code, the syntax would be this:

```
void CreateCanvasWithEllipse(double desiredLeft, double desiredTop)
{
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
    Ellipse ellipse = SomeEllipseConstructionMethod();
    Canvas.SetLeft(ellipse, desiredLeft);
    Canvas.SetTop(ellipse, desiredTop);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried those in code but doesn't work. I did this: `ellipse.Canvas.Left`, but there is no `Canvas` property on an `Ellipse` object.

Comment: I edited my answer to show the C# syntax.  The Canvas.Left property (and .Top, .Bottom, .Right) are attached properties.  See the overview at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx